# Unable to open eclipse marketplace

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-marketplace

I have installed eclipse kepler 64 bit on ubuntu 13.04 64 bit.

when i try to open the eclipse marketplace, i am getting following error :

```
Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace
Cannot install remote marketplace locations: Cannot complete request to http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p: Content is not allowed in prolog.
Cannot complete request to http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p: Content is not allowed in prolog.
Content is not allowed in prolog.
Cannot complete request to http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p: Content is not allowed in prolog.
Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

then i checked the log and found following :

```
eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.M20130911-1000
java.version=1.7.0_25
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_IN
Framework arguments:  -vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

Error
Sun Sep 29 20:57:29 IST 2013
Cannot parse XML at URL http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1236)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.DefaultCatalogService.listCatalogs(DefaultCatalogService.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.MarketplaceWizardCommand$5.run(MarketplaceWizardCommand.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

i also tried to open the url : http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p

but it gives following response :

```
This file is part of MediaWiki and is not a valid entry point
```

So i am wondering why this error occurred ??

Comment: Ask this question at [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: @HansUp the problem is not with ubuntu, its with eclipse.
if i am getting the same error on windows, then where should i ask ?

Comment: Eclipse marketplace server is down.

Comment: Got the same error. Even I think the marketplace server is down, since   the error has not been reported before in Google's indexes.

Comment: Same issue here, running OS X.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The response of http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p is probably also your answer.

I'm having the same problem in Windows 7. And since i couldn't find anything on Google either i'm guessing this is a temporary problem caused by some bug at the marketplace.eclipse.org server. 
I've tried installing Kepler for Java programmers and the Standard edition, both return the same error when trying to access the marketplace.

Good luck.

Comment: Same problem is being reported in the Eclipse newsgroups

Answer (score 4):

I found [this](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/270718/) which suggested adding `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` to your .ini file.

This worked for me when I had the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue with Windows XP and solved it by adding the site which caused the problem **http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p** under **Window → Preferences → Install/Update → Available software Site**

This helped me solve the issue and able to install the plugin using Eclipse Marketplace.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot access the marketplace via Eclipse as well (win 7 pro x64, no antivirus/firewall active at the moment). I also tried to download the eclipse theme plugin from http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=181 by clicking 'Download from Eclipse Marketplace' - same error: 'This file is part of MediaWiki and is not a valid entry point'. Most likely the whole marketplace is down.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is eclipse marketplace. Server probably down or another problem.

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/

```
This file is part of MediaWiki and is not a valid entry point
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't also access to http://marketplace.eclipse.org/
It currently gives an error:

> *This file is part of MediaWiki and is not a valid entry point*

So only think to do is wait for marketplace server to be online again

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same issue, probably issue with Eclipse Market Place site, its not something to do with Windows 7 or Ubuntu. 
I am running on VM, which has Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS, response is same on both environments.
We may have to wait for the Eclipse Market place to be up.

Comment: Hope the Eclipse Market Place is up now, i am able to use it.

Comment: It is not still up till now

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem now (1.2. 2015). Look at the picture. **Eclipse Market place not working, unable to open it.**

It takes two days and eclipse market place is still inaccessible. You can ping server, but service is not working. When I asked support, they told me, the problem should be on their side. So, in my opinion, it have not connection with your distribution in most cases. You have to wait, until they fix it.

You can bypass it by using update sites in 90% cases.

[image]